# Remove logicaldrive in Smart Array P420i

Tags: raid, hp, hp-smart-array

i've a DL380p with Smart Array P420i. On this server we have some logicaldrives:

```
root@server:~# hpacucli ctrl all show config

Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: XXXXXXX)

   array A (Solid State SATA, Unused Space: 0  MB)


      logicaldrive 1 (119.2 GB, RAID 0, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:2:1 (port 1I:box 2:bay 1, Solid State SATA, 128.0 GB, OK)

   array B (SATA, Unused Space: 0  MB)


      logicaldrive 2 (1.8 TB, RAID 1+0, Failed)

      physicaldrive 1I:2:2 (port 1I:box 2:bay 2, SATA, 250.0 GB, Failed)
      physicaldrive 1I:2:3 (port 1I:box 2:bay 3, SATA, 250.0 GB, Failed)
      physicaldrive 1I:2:4 (port 1I:box 2:bay 4, SATA, 2 TB, Failed)
      physicaldrive 2I:2:5 (port 2I:box 2:bay 5, SATA, 2 TB, Failed)

   array C (Solid State SATA, Unused Space: 0  MB)


      logicaldrive 3 (931.5 GB, RAID 0, OK)

      physicaldrive 2I:2:6 (port 2I:box 2:bay 6, Solid State SATA, 1 TB, OK)

   array D (Solid State SATA, Unused Space: 0  MB)


      logicaldrive 4 (931.5 GB, RAID 0, OK)

      physicaldrive 2I:2:7 (port 2I:box 2:bay 7, Solid State SATA, 1 TB, OK)

   array E (Solid State SATA, Unused Space: 0  MB)


      logicaldrive 5 (931.5 GB, RAID 0, OK)

      physicaldrive 2I:2:8 (port 2I:box 2:bay 8, Solid State SATA, 1 TB, OK)

   SEP (Vendor ID XXXX, Model XXXXX) 380 (WWID: XXXXXXX)
```

The array B, shout removed from logicaldrives, but when i run this command:

```
root@server:~# hpacucli ctrl slot=0 ld 2 delete

Warning: Deleting an array can cause other array letters to become renamed.
         E.g. Deleting array A from arrays A,B,C will result in two remaining
         arrays A,B ... not B,C


Warning: Deleting the specified device(s) will result in data being lost.
         Continue? (y/n) n
```

Before i want to delete this logicaldrives i want to ask if i delete this ld, the letter will be renamed or not? Because i want to recreate this array B with the same letter. So i can reboot this system to do this steps, but i want to do this steps without downtime. Can anybody help?

Best

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running debian 10.2

Answer (score 0):

Array labeling uses contiguous letters.  If you delete array B, then your current arrays C, D, and E will become B, C, and D, respectively.  These array letters are something that ACU uses for convenience in referring to a group of disks.  Your operating system sees logical volumes, not arrays, so re-lettering the arrays shouldn't have a big impact unless you have array letters hard-coded in a script somewhere.